# Design pattern allow inherited permissions

Tags: design-patterns

i'm trying to implement local settings that can inherit from  general settings.

one idea come to my head is using empty values for settings i want it to inherit from global settings then merge both settings together (global and local) to get the final settings

 example in php:

```
$localSettings = ['setting1'=>'value1','setting2=>'value2','setting3'=>null];

//of course the null value will be unsetted
unset($localSettings['setting3']);

$generalSettings = ['setting1'=>'value1','setting2=>'value2','setting3'=>'value3'];

$settings = array_merge($generalSettings ,$localSettings);
```

any idea how i could implement such case using design patterns ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that it is preferable to keep the local and global settings separate and only do the merge when you actually want to access a setting.

Two object-oriented patterns come to mind to achive this [Facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) and [Composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)/[Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

### Facade

Construct the facade object with references to the two settings objects and provide a simple interface to get a particular setting. In C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

class Settings {
  using SettingsType = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>;
 private:
  const SettingsType* local_;
  const SettingsType* global_;
 public:
  Settings(const SettingsType* local, const SettingsType* global) 
    : local_(local), global_(global) {}

  std::string get(const std::string& key) {
    if (local_) {
      auto element = local_->find(key);
      if (element != local_->end())
        return element->second; 
    }
    if (global_) {
      auto element = global_->find(key);
      if (element != global_->end())
        return element->second;
    }
    return "";
  }
};

int main() {
  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> global_settings;
  global_settings["ip"] = "127.0.0.1";
  global_settings["port"] = "8080";

  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> local_settings;  
  local_settings["hostname"] = "example.com";
  local_settings["port"] = "12345"; // Overrride global setting

  Settings settings(&global_settings, &local_settings);

  std::cout << "ip: " << settings.get("ip") << "\n";
  std::cout << "port: " << settings.get("port") << "\n";
  std::cout << "hostname: " << settings.get("hostname") << "\n";
}
```

[Live demo.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9df91783f17e6ff)

### Composite/Decorator

A more flexible, encapsulated solution would be to use something similar to the Composite/Decorator pattern and compose the local settings object with the global settings object:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

class Settings {
 private:
  const Settings* parent_settings_;
  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> settings_;

 public:
  Settings() : parent_settings_(nullptr) {}
  Settings(const Settings* parent) : parent_settings_(parent) {}

  void set(const std::string& key, const std::string &value) {
    settings_[key] = value;
  }

  std::string get(const std::string& key) const {
    auto found = settings_.find(key);
    if (found != settings_.end())
      return found->second;
    if (parent_settings_)
      return parent_settings_->get(key);
    return "";
  }
};

int main() {
  Settings global_settings;
  global_settings.set("ip", "127.0.0.1");
  global_settings.set("port", "8080");

  Settings local_settings(global_settings);
  local_settings.set("hostname", "example.com");
  local_settings.set("port", "12345"); // Overrride global settings

  std::cout << "ip: " << local_settings.get("ip") << "\n";
  std::cout << "port: " << local_settings.get("port") << "\n";
  std::cout << "hostname: " << local_settings.get("hostname") << "\n";
}
```

[Live demo.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb029b8734f810bb)

Hope that helps.